# Whats the difference between SPListItem["property"] and SPListItem.Properties["property"]?

Tags: sharepoint

I've been working with the SharePoint object model and got that question.

Answer (score 4):

aListItem["property"] is not correct
It is aListItem["fieldName"]

So:

```
aListItem["property"]
```

will get the value of the field named "property"

and

```
aListitem.Properties["property"]
```

will get the value of the property "Property" (eg List)